# i want a card loop in html bootstrap but it didnot work properly the cards vertically align after each other

Tags: html, angular, bootstrap-4

I want to create cards in a loop runtime but the card show vertically align eachother i gave the col-md-4 but it didnot work
`enter code here`

```
<div class="row-fluid border mt-3">
<div *ngFor="let data of allWidgets">

    <div class="col-md-4 border mt-3">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="img1">
                <img src="https://images.havenly.com/unsafe/550x334/filters:quality(50)/https://s3.amazonaws.com/static.havenly.com/assets/2a35d539-e889-405e-b495-815aa33f65ea" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="img2">
                <img src="https://images.havenly.com/unsafe/180x180/filters:quality(50)/https://s3.amazonaws.com/havenlydesignerphotos/13078-profile-eb69eheadshot02.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="mian-text mt-0">
                <p>{{data.name}}</p>
                <p><small>{{data.description}} </small> </p>
             <a href="" class="mr-5">View Profile</a> <span style="color: lightgray;">|</span> <a href="" class="ml-5">Select Cherise</a>

                
            </div>
           
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you must use the ngFor not on the first div but on the second like this :

```
<div class="col-md-4 border mt-3" *ngFor="let data of allWidgets">
```

this is the solution of your problem.
if you want to create a good angular card you must see:https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/angular/

is the most used site in angular.
have a nice day :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, sir for your help Ill Appreciate that .

Comment: np if you like my help vote my answer as the beast ;)